# Zune HD won't wirelessly sync with my laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, sync, zune, zune-hd

I've got a Zune HD and I am having trouble getting it to sync with my laptop.

I have gone through the procedures listed on their webpage:

> http://www.Zune.net/en-us/support/usersguide/musicvideospictures/troubleshootwireless.htm

But still can't get it to work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the Zune doesn't register on the wifi router as a named device, but rather as a 'guest' (even though it still needs the WPA2 key, etc).  I had to create a special rule on my router to allow guest devices to see the machines on my network.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that Zune doesn't yet support 802.11 **N** wifi signal yet...you have to use 802.11 **G,B, or A**

onece I switched my router to G my wireless sync works amazing

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any more information on this situation? You're not giving us enough information to critically examine your issue. Is your firewall turned off? Is the Zune Wireless Bus Enumerator service enabled? Have you restarted your PC? What operating system are you using?

There are so many situational things that could be wrong right now, and we have no clue.

We need more information.

Comment: Firewall is set to allow all, all Zune Wireless services are enabled, I have restarted my pc, and I'm running Windows 7 (the RC)

Comment: Is the Zune connected to the network properly? Can you verify communication between the access point and the zune? In my experience, getting the zune to work with windows 7 was just a matter of futzing around with the settings/configs.

Comment: The zune is connecting to my network, and I can see it attach on my router's webpage.